# how to get for loops to iterate through every element in subsequent calls to function

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion

Below, is a simplified version of the original code I posted. When the code runs, it goes through its first iteration of the for loop, finds an element that meets the condition (the first element )and calls another instance of the function. NOTE: In my understanding of recursion, the first instance of the function has 'frozen' awaiting to iterate to the next element once the 2nd instance of the function has completed, popping off the call stack
However when the 2nd instance of the function finishes, the first instance of the function does not resume. why?? What am I missing here??

```
class Solution:
    def main(self,x,y):

        self.directions = [(-1, 0), (0, -1), (1, 0), (0,1)]
        self.changed = {}
        self.func_count = 0

        self.helper(x,y)


    def helper(self, x, y):

        self.func_count += 1
        print("func count ", self.func_count)


        for i, j in self.directions:

            print("for loop in func count", self.func_count)

            # here is the problem. Once a x+i, y+j meets the below
            # conditon, the self.helper func runs and never
            # comes back to finish the iteration.. why??

            print("x+i, y+j", x+i, y+j)

            if x + i == 0 and y + j == 0:

                if (x+i,y+j) not in self.changed:

                    x = x + i
                    y = y + j

                    self.helper(x,y)



S = Solution()
S.main(0,1)
```

Comment: Hi! Could you please try to work out a minimal reproducible example? I.e., a smaller piece of code that is enough to reproduce the issue, without diluting in in all the rest?

Comment: edited for simplicity. thanks stef

Comment: Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question into a different question is against policy when doing so invalidates one or more answers, even if the original question isn't what you really intended to ask. Your edit here invalidated an answer. Users with edit privileges should proactively revert such changes. I've reverted your edit. You're *encouraged to [ask a new Question](/questions/ask)*, perhaps linking this one for additional context. We want to help, but your new/additional issue needs to be a new Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code always refer to `self.func_count`, which is the same for all recursive calls~(i.e., every function call increments and overwrites the same copy of `func_count`). Thus, it *looks like* the function never resumes.

You can fix this by defining a `local_func_count`:

```
self.func_count += 1
local_func_count = self.func_count
```

and using it:

```
print("for loop in func count", local_func_count)
```

---

There's another potential bug in your code: `self.changed` is never updated.